# How do you convert a python time.struct_time object into a ISO string?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a Python object:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=11, tm_min=57, tm_sec=12, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=284, tm_isdst=0)
```

And I need to get an [ISO string](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

```
'2013-10-11T11:57:12Z'
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using [`time.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) is perhaps easiest:

```
iso = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', timetup)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> timetup = time.gmtime()
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', timetup)
'2013-10-11T13:31:03Z'
```

You can also use a `datetime.datetime()` object, which has a [`datetime.isoformat()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) method:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime(*timetup[:6]).isoformat()
'2013-10-11T13:31:03'
```

This misses the timezone `Z` marker; you could just add that.

Comment: It should be noted that this assumes that `timetup` refers to UTC ('Z').

Comment: @MrFuppes only because I used `time.gmtime()` to create it; the OP didn’t show how they had created theirs. You can also use `time.localtime()`, but given that the expected output included a `Z` (UTC timezone) marker and the formatted time matched their `timeup` value, it was a reasonable assumption that they had used `time.gmtime()` to create it.

Answer (score 0):

```
iso = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', timetup)
```

The last format charater ‘Z’ is not necessary, such as

```
iso = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', timetup)
```

You will get time string like '2015-11-05 02:09:57'